# install Sitecore 8.2 on Azure Deployment Slot

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore8.2

I was able to provision new environment using the Sitecore 8.2.1 ARM templates. I can create a staging slot on for CD/CM but how do I install Sitecore on a deployment slot. I refereed to this [article](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/TodoApp.json), although not specific to Sitecore
but that just creates a slot. Cant figure out how to run the ARM template to provision authoring and delivery on a staging slot. I am new to Sitecore, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for how to update the Sitecore 8.2.1 ARM Template to deploy your Sitecore on a Staging slot instead of the production slot?

Comment: Hi juvchan,yes that is correct. i provisioned the env using ARM template but by default it puts the apps on the default slot (prod). I created a new slot called 'staging' on CM web app but when the browse it, i get the 'app service created' page not the sistecore page

Comment: Got it, are you able to share the ARM Template link? Do you want all the web apps to be on staging slot or just the CM one?

Comment: https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates

Comment: I just want CD and CM on staging slots. I am not worried about application settings at this stage, so they can use the same connection string and other settins

Comment: whick sku are you using? xP0, xP, xM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135336/discussion-between-mahesh-kava-and-juvchan).

Answer (score -1):

I have written an example of an ARM Templates to create an Azure Web App Slot with the Sitecore XM config:
https://github.com/mathieu-benoit/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/Sitecore%208.2.1/my-xm-slot

Please, feel free to reuse and adapt for your own needs!

Hope that helps!